# Bootable USB gives grub menu

Tags: grub2, usb-drive

Used these instructions for creating a bootable Ubuntu USB https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

I am using a UbuntuMATE ISO

I formatted my usb as ExFAt with GTD partitioning.

Everything works as expected, holding option key on reboot(on a Mac) I successfully boot off the USB. However, instead of booting Ubuntu, I get a grub menu screen prompt. How do I boot Ubuntu from grub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unetbooting will install its own bootloader. Best to skip Unetbooting and simply write the img file unto the USB stick.

You can use this guide:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick?_ga=1.32216954.591343902.1481129338
And
https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/ch04s03.html.en

Another option is to use rufus. Unfortunately it only runs on Windows so either use a Windows machine or run it in a virtual machine. 
https://rufus.akeo.ie/

Comment: BTW, you should just be able to copy the img file contents onto a fat 32 formated USB and it should work..

Comment: good to know! unetbootin (windows) didn't work for me either when trying to create a centos 7 usb. There is a manual install for Mac users here as well https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick?_ga=1.32216954.591343902.1481129338

Comment: Good find! I'll add it to the answer above.